# Angular 7 Image zoom is not working on mouse hover

Tags: angular7

**My requirement is to zoom the image when mouse hovers over that image**

I am using this package in my Angular6 Project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom

Here is the stackblitz editor url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocompcus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I can't find out where it went wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [zoomMode]="'click'" to enable zoom on click
- Use [zoomMode]="'hover'" to enable zoom on hover

I've updated the stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocompcus-j5kujt.

Comment: @AkhilVenkataSaiGrandhi, Can you try on my Stackblitz WS? It's working fine in my WS..

Comment: Yes u have used 2 images but I need with one image. But as I didnt mention it in my question, U gave the correct answer

Comment: @AkhilVenkataSaiGrandhi As per the npm lib doc we need two images, one is thumbImage and another fullImage so if you remove any of them it will not work. Basically, fullImage is overlapping over the thumbImage, so if you really wanna use this feature then you need to create two same image with diffrent resolution. I think now I'm able to clear your doubt, thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

Its working by adding [magnification]="2" for singleimage without adding [fullImage]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this similar angular image zoom npm package [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier). Here is a working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-img-magnifier). This is very easy to implement and fully customizable.

```
<ng-img-magnifier [thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'
    [top]='top' [right]='right'
    [lensWidth]='lensewidth' [lensHeight]='lensheight'
    [resultWidth]='resultWidth' [resultHeight]='resultheight'
    [imgWidth]='imgWidth' [imgHeight]='imgheight'>
</ng-img-magnifier>
```